# Temporary file deleted

Tags: ed

I'm working on ed (yes, the editor) source code.
The program uses a scratch file, opened with tmpfile, as a buffer.
But, whenever I run the program, lsof always report the temporary file as deleted! (and in fact it's not there). Why?

Comment: Presumeably it clears the current temp (scratch) file on start up.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you. The editor has a single current buffer; this buffer must reside somewhere, and upon my inspection on source code it's clear it's not in memory. So?

Comment: You can delete (unlink) a file you have open in your program - the file still exists & you can read from and write to it. It's just not visible in the filesystem.

Comment: Oh, I got it! I checked glibc source code: tmpfile unlinks the file just after creating it, so it is completely deleted upon closing of the stream. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @Mat why don't you just make that an answer since … you know … it's the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

Because a file can exist on disk without having a filename associated with it, many programs will open a file and then promptly unlink it. The file contents can continue to be modified & read by open file-handles on the file, and won't actually be removed from the disk until all open file handles are closed.

(this is for *nix/POSIX platforms AFAICT; Windows handles files differently, preventing unlinking if an program has the file-handle still open, and thus reboots are often needed for upgrades to force those open file-handles to be closed so file contents can be replaced)